# findViewById doesn't seem to return correct view type?

Tags: android, casting, findviewbyid

Since we don't have to cast anymore, I expected `findViewById` to return the correct type, but it doesn't seem to do that. I'm obviously making a very simple mistake here, can you point it out?

I have a `TextView`'s ID (since I created it dynamically) and want to change the text size of that item, this snippet works fine:

```html
        TextView tmpView = findViewById(chain.getIngredientNameId());
        tmpView.setTextSize(8);
```

But this one doesn't:

```html
        findViewById(chain.getIngredientNameId()).setTextSize(8);
```

So I assume I have to case it to `TextView` but none of my attempts seems to work (using () or <>), what obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: What does "none of my attempts seems to work" mean? What is the exact syntax that you tried, and what was the specific result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast it if do not save to variable.

```
TextView tmpView = findViewById(chain.getIngredientNameId());          //TextVeiw
((TextView) findViewById(chain.getIngredientNameId())).setTextSize(8); // TextVeiw
findViewById(chain.getIngredientNameId());                             // View
```

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for the second line, I didn't have the extra () around the first part, like I said, obvious (now), thanks